# ruby on rails route params in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

routes.rb:

```
match 'first/#!/:name' => 'first#first'
```

first_controller.rb:

```
class FirstController < ApplicationController
  def first
    @name = params[:name]
  end
end
```

But the `@name` variable is nil when I render the url: http://localhost:3000/first/#!/sayuj

Please help

Comment: Hash-bang URLs are usually used by JavaScript for routing, not for server-side routing. Why are you doing it like that?

Comment: I agree with Skilldrick. I think there is some XY syndrome going on here. Can you elaborate as to why you need to use hashbang URLs?

Answer (score 10):

Anything after the first `#` in the URL is not (usually) sent back to the server; it's used on client side only.

So the URL `http://localhost:3000/first/#!/sayuj` in the client will actually call the URL `http://localhost:3000/first/` on server side.

See the following posts for more info:

- http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html
- http://www.webmonkey.com/2011/02/gawker-learns-the-hard-way-why-hash-bang-urls-are-evil/
- http://dannythorpe.com/2011/02/09/side-effects-of-hash-bang-urls/
- http://rc3.org/2011/02/09/hash-bang-urls-and-overuse-of-ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Jits is correct that the # in the url will drop the rest of the url, also, I believe your route is incorrect, it should look like:

```
match 'first/:name', :to => 'first#first'
```

documentation is at [Engine yard rails 3 routes.](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/)

Comment: Rails 3 routing supports shorthand that will let his existing code work. Saying `match 'first/:name' => 'first#first'` is fine. Also if he were using a name method in `FirstController` the other shorthand method could be used to say simply: `match 'first/name'` and rails with link it up accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I did not know you could shorthand that even further.